# What's the best approach to structure a project plan for a JSF project?

Tags: software-development, planning

We're a Software Development Company that's about to start working on a JSF (JavaServer Faces) project with a Hibernate persistence layer. I'm managing the project, and we have 2 developers on the team that were recently introduced to JSF. What's the best approach to structure the project plan?

Some issues on my mind:

1. Breakdown of tasks.
2. Should developers work on different parts of the same module or should each one handle his own module?

Please add/suggest any other issues you think I should take into consideration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is not a simple question, and I won't insult it with a simplistic answer.

I'm asked that question frequently at work, and the best answer I've found is to point to [Herding Cats](http://herdingcats.typepad.com/my_weblog/2012/12/project-controls-is-the-basis-of-project-management.html) by G. Allman.  He doesn't have a short simple answer, but he has a coherent answer that he explains consistently.  Basically you have to decide what "done" looks like, then break that down into *capabilities* that have meaning to the customer and can be measured.  Then break that down into deliverables and work packages till either it will cost more to measure progress than to create progress or until the work is < 2 weeks.

For your second question, if the answer doesn't arise naturally from the WBS, then I'd submit a second question to PM:SE, and invite CodeGnome to explain self-organizing teams.

Comment: Thanks. I read your reply and the Herding cats link. They are useful. However, I need specific information that has to do with breaking down a _JSF_ project. **Example:** Plan item for **Managed Beans**. Another item for **Validations**, etc...

Comment: I'll accept this answer because it gave me guidelines regarding how to think when preparing a plan.